# unidirectional one to many relationship querying GORM grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

```
Author{
 String name;
 List<Book> books
 static hasMany= [books: Book]
}
```

---

```
Book{
 int number_of_pages;
 String name;
}
```

I want to query and fetch top 10 books for a specific author sorted by `number_of_pages`

Comment: Any reason/s to use underscores instead of camelCase in number_of_pages? The convention in Java (thus in groovy) is camel case.

Answer (score 2):

Using HQL you can do:

```
    def query = "select book from Author author join author.books book where author=:author order by book.number_of_pages"
    def books = Author.executeQuery(query, [author: author], [max: 10])
```

Note: you should rename `number_of_pages` to `numberOfPages`.

Comment: it says `could not resolve property: books of Author`, I am putting it in getBooks() method in Author

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make Author visible to Book, by adding an author as an attribute for Book.

This way you could do:

```
Book.findAll(sort: 'number_of_pages', max: 10) { author.id == myAuthorVariable.id }
```

Although, there's a much better way. If you make Author implement equals method, you can write:

```
Book.findAll(sort: 'number_of_pages', max: 10) { author == myAuthorVariable }
```

Additionally, you can set an 'offset', this is, bring me 10 books starting from the x register. This is usefull for pagination:

```
Book.findAll(sort: 'number_of_pages', max: 10, offset: 50) { author == myAuthorVariable }
```

An implementation of equals for Author could be:

```
def boolean equals(author) {
    if (this.is(author)) return true

    if (!author || getClass() != author.class) return false

    return this.name == author.name
}
```

Comment: I can't add it because Organization is an entity which has Books too